# Determine dimension of mapping function Phi from form of Kernel

Tags: kernel-trick

If I have a kernel of the form $k(x, y)  = (x^Ty)^n$ where $x$ and $y$ are **d**-dimensional, how can I determine the dimension of the mapping function $\phi(x)$, in terms of **n** and **d**, without explicitly solving for $\phi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel is a homogenious polynomial kernel (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_kernel). Check the Wikipedia page for an example of what are the explicit features for an arbitrary $d$ and $n=2$ (and take $c=0$ in your case): in this particular case of $n=2$, $\phi(\mathbf{x})$ has dimension $d(d+1)/2$ (because there are $d(d+1)/2$ cross-products including the squares).

Another example: if $d=2$ and $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2)$, and $n=3$, you will need to form the features $\phi(\mathbf{x}) = (x_1^3, x_2^3, \sqrt{3} x_1^2x_2, \sqrt{3} x_2^2x_1)$, so in this particular case $\phi(x)$ has dimension 4. Note that $3+0=3=n$, $0+3=3$, $1+2=3$, and $2+1=3$.

So more generally what you have is as much features as all the cross-product of the $d$ variables and their power so that their total sum of powers is $n$. Now according to this Wikipedia page [about the number of combinations with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) (which is the number of possibilities to have $d$ integers $k_1$... $k_d$ such that their sum is $n$), the total number of features you need to form (hence the dimension of your explicit feature space) should be $\binom{n + d - 1}{n}$ (see also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283603/how-to-find-the-total-number-of-distinct-terms-in-a-certain-expansion)).